# How do I set the BSOD on Windows 8.1 to pause and display useful hexdump information instead of a frowny face?

Tags: windows, crash, bsod

My Windows 8.1 machine is crashing once-a-day with a BSOD, and not leaving any DMP file behind, so I have nothing for WinDbg.exe to examine. Nothing interesting in the event log.

The BSOD used to have all sorts of useful information on the screen about the cause of the system crash.

Can that old-style BSOD be selected instead of the frowny face? So the BSOD will have useful hexdump technical information, since there is no *.DMP file for my crashes.

The BSOD also auto-reboots. Is there a way to prevent the auto-reboot as well? If so, how?

Windows 8.1, all service packs applied, all device drivers update-to-date, on an HP Z420.

(Redirected to Super User from Stack Overflow.)

---

UPDATE Feb-10

The morning's awaiting BSOD had this information:
KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (storport.sys)

Still no DMP file.

---

UPDATE Feb-11

The morning's awaiting BSOD had this information:
DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (storport.sys)

Still no DMP file.

Dug around in the registry and found out the mini-dumps were turned off.  If the stars are aligned, I've properly enabled mini-dumps in the registry.

Updated the Intel C600 Series Chipset SAS RAID and SATA RAID controller drivers (RSTe: Rapid Storage Technology enterprise) from 3.5.1.1008 9/14/2012 to the current drivers on the Intel site 3.8.0.1106 8/14/2013.

---

UPDATE Feb-12

No BSOD.  Yet.  Maybe the updated Intel RSTe drivers did the trick.

---

UPDATE Mar-07

No BSOD for weeks.  Seems the C600 3.8.0.1106 resolved the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just disable the auto-reboot? Disable it the same way you did it on previous version of Windows.  As for changing the appearence of the BSOD that won't be possible.  The error code is a great start if you want help from us.

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to be able to get:  an error code.

Like the kind that used to appear on the older BSOD.  Since there is nothing in the events log, and there is no DMP file.

Comment: I have just updated the HP Z420 BIOS from 2.12 01/28/2013 to 3.65 12/19/2013.  Perhaps the crash was due to a BIOS issue, since 3.18 appears to have fixed a crashing problem.

Comment: Without the DMP file we can't say and would only be speculating.